# Trying to install 13.04 or 12.04 or 12.10 on macbook pro 2010 with 17" display

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, macbook, 13.04

I had no problems with the installation, following the instructions on the wiki. Afterwards I got a huge problem though. I am currently seeking advice how to proceed.

I get the background color of ubuntu plus some glitches in the place where the menu should be. It's just the screen after the first launch after reboot.

It's just a basic install, I haven't touched on configurations yet. I can't do anything with the OS as it is no terminal no nothing. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to switch to Console mode from GUI mode in GNOME follow this simple steps
To switch to Console mode **Press ‘Ctrl + Alt + F1′ (F2 -- F6)**

To switch between consoles in Console mode **Press ‘Alt + F1′ (F2 -- F6)**

To switch back to GNOME GUI mode **Press ‘Alt + F7′**

On terminal, type **sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name** to determine your exact Macbook Pro model then check the relevant article from the following link

**https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro**

P.S. the only available Wiki for Ubuntu 13.04 is for MacbookPro 10,2.

Answer (score 0):

I have Ubuntu 13.04 running on a Macbook Pro 2009, 5,3 edition, one big issue I have with it is the power management, when the ACPI is active, there are some kind of conflicts with the nVidia graphic card driver.

You should try booting without ACPI in order to see if the system is more stable or not. In order to do that, you can edit your GRUB2 when you boot the computer. Press Shift when you boot and you should see the GRUB menu. Select "Advanced options", then "e" in order to edit the GRUB2 file. There's a line in here with parameters like "ro quiet splash". Add to it the parameter "ACPI=off". It means the kernel won't try to handle the power management of your computer. Once you added the line, press F10 in order to boot with the modification.

ACPI=off is not a solution as Ubuntu can't handle power management at all with it, meaning it won't be able to suspend/hibernate neither "see" the battery (but you can still work on battery). I'm fighting with it for few weeks now and didn't find a solution yet.